# Has Powershell v2 been released?

Tags: powershell

Has Powershell v2 been released?

I found CTP 3 that was released in Dec 08 but I can't find a final download for v2...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Yes](https://connect.microsoft.com/windowsmanagement/Downloads).  Powershell v2.0 for Windows XP SP3 can be downloaded from [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/windowsmanagement/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=21763).  Released 9/9/2009.

Comment: I found out that a) that download doesn't work with Firefox, it seems to rely on an ActiveX plugin. Plus, you need to uninstall PowerShell 1.0 first which is semi-hard because it's not shown in the Add/remove programs dialog until you check "Show updates" (then it's under Windows)...

Comment: You don't need the plugin if you just click on the "download file" on the right of each item.

Comment: Hmmm, according to the Powershell Blog this is only a RC version :o| http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2009/09/10/xp-and-w2k3-release-candidate-versions-of-powershell-are-now-available-for-download.aspx

Comment: That's really confusing.  It appears on the download page, that it's a release candidate version of Windows Management Framework, but a released version of Powershell 2.0 ... my whole world is upside down now.

Answer (score 3):

Yes (in Windows 7) and no, there is not a seperate installer for older systems available... It seems to be [in the pipeline](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2009/07/23/windows-powershell-2-0-rtm.aspx) though.

> In the next few months, we will release a downlevel package for installing Windows PowerShell 2.0 on Windows XP SP3, Windows 2003 SP2, Windows Vista-SP1 and Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

It is already released with Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2. See the [PowerShell Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/default.aspx) for when the download is available. They currently have the Release Candidate available for download [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/windowsmanagement/Downloads) included in Windows Management Framework Core.